# Opencart Category Groups

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

Установил модуль [Category Groups](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9531&filter_username=JanesOosthuizen), при выводе на [странице](http://facebike.net/mitia/), происходит дублирование всего содержимого XDCategoryGroups.tpl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XDCategoryGroups.tpl

```html
<style type="text/css">
    <?php echo $XDcustomCSSCode; ?>
    .customSizes {
        padding-left:<?php echo $XDPaddingLeft; ?>px;
        padding-right:<?php echo $XDPaddingRight; ?>px;
        height:<?php echo $XDBlockHeight; ?>px;
    }
</style>
<div class="box1">
      <?php 
      foreach($categories as $category) {
      
        // ADD CONDITIONAL INFO FOR SIZING
      
       if($XDAutoPadding == 'active'){
            $spacingClass = 'customSizes';
       } else {
            $spacingClass = 'autoSpacing';
       }
      
        ?>
        <div class="XDCategoryGroupsBlocks <?php echo $spacingClass; ?>">
            <?php 

            if($XDposition == 'aboveImage') {
                if($XDtitleLinks == 'active'){
                ?><h2><a href="<?php echo $category['parent_url']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></h2><?php
                } else {
                ?><h2><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h2><?php
                }
            } 
            
            if($XDshowImage == 'yes') {
                if($XDtitleLinks == 'active'){
                  ?><a href="<?php echo $category['parent_url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"/></a><?php
                } else {
                  ?><img class="categoryGroupImg" src="<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"/><?php
                }
            }

            if($XDposition == 'belowImage') {
                if($XDtitleLinks == 'active'){
                    ?><h2><a href="<?php echo $category['parent_url']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></h2><?php
                } else {
                    ?><h2><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h2><?php
                }
            } ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach($category['children'] as $childElement){
                echo '<li><a href="'.$childElement['url'].'">'.$childElement['name'].'</a></li>';
            } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
</div>
```

controller - XDCategoryGroups.php

```html
<?php
class ControllerModuleXDCategoryGroups extends Controller { 
 protected function index() {
            $this->language->load('module/XDCategoryGroups');
            $this->load->model('catalog/category');
            $this->load->model('tool/image');
            
            //$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
            
            if (file_exists('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/XDCategoryGroups.css')) {
                    $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/XDCategoryGroups.css');
            } else {
                    $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/XDCategoryGroups.css');
            }
            
            $categories = $this->config->get('XDCategoryGroupsBlocks');
            
            $XDSettings = $this->config->get('XDCategoryGroupsSetting');
            
            $this->data['XDposition'] = $XDSettings['titlePosition'];
            $this->data['XDtitleLinks'] = $XDSettings['titleLinks'];
            $this->data['XDshowImage'] = $XDSettings['showImage'];
            $this->data['XDAutoPadding'] = $XDSettings['blockPadding'];
            $this->data['XDPaddingLeft'] = $XDSettings['blockPaddingLeft'];
            $this->data['XDPaddingRight'] = $XDSettings['blockPaddingRight'];
            $this->data['XDBlockHeight'] = $XDSettings['blockHeight'];
            $this->data['XDcustomCSSCode'] = (isset($XDSettings['customCSSCode']) ? $XDSettings['customCSSCode'] : '');

            if(!isset($XDSettings['customImageWidth']) || $XDSettings['customImageWidth'] == ''){
                $XDSettings['customImageWidth'] = 250;
            }
    
            
            $subCatLimit = $XDSettings['categoryLimit'];
            
            $cat = array();
            $count = 1;
            $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
            foreach($categories as $category){
                $currentCategory = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category['category_id']);

                $cat[$count]['name'] = $currentCategory['name'];
                $cat[$count]['parent_url'] = $this->constructPath($category['category_id']);
                if($category['image'] == ''){
                    $cat[$count]['image'] = '/image/no_image.jpg';
                } else {
                    //$cat[$count]['image'] = HTTPS_SERVER.'image/'.$category['image'];
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], $XDSettings['customImageWidth'], $XDSettings['customImageWidth']);
                    $cat[$count]['image'] = $image;
                }
                
                $cat[$count]['category'] = $category['category_id'];
                $CategoryChildren = array();
                $Children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);
                $Children = array_slice($Children, 0, $subCatLimit);
                foreach($Children as $child){
                    $CategoryChildren[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name'        => $child['name'],
                        'url'         => $this->constructPath($category['category_id'], $child['category_id'])
                    );
                }
                $cat[$count]['children'] = $CategoryChildren;
                
                $count++;
            }
            
            $this->data['categories'] = $cat;
            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/XDCategoryGroups.tpl')) {
                    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/XDCategoryGroups.tpl';
            } else {
                    $this->template = 'default/template/module/XDCategoryGroups.tpl';
            }
            
            $this->render();
        }
        
        protected function constructPath($categoryID,$subCategoryID = '') {
            if($subCategoryID != ''){
                $new_path = $categoryID . '_' . $subCategoryID;
            } else {
                $new_path = $categoryID;
            }
                 
            //$categoryhome = array();
      //$category_id = array_shift($this->path);
      //$results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($parent_id);
                
            $categoryURL = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $new_path);
  
  return $categoryURL;
        }
}
?>
```

Использую ocStore Версия 1.5.5.1.2

Comment: Вы точно модуль два раза в админке не вывели на главную?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit к сожалению - нет http://prntscr.com/b2pija  

но когда добавляют еще один вывод, то и его дублирует т.е. вместо двух 4